# Get data Fund flows of ETFs in pine script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

in the tradingview chart, I can select the fields to plot: Discount/Premium to NAV or Fund flows for ETFs. But how can I use Pine Scipt code to call these fields to combine with other indicators in my strategy in Pine Script?

I try to find in request syntax but I can't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can import chart values into the strategy script using the built-in `input.source()` function and manually select the desired plot in the strategy settings.
https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_input.source

> Adds an input to the Inputs tab of your script's Settings, which allows you to provide configuration options to script users. This function adds a dropdown that allows the user to select a source for the calculation, e.g. close, hl2, etc. The user can also select an output from another indicator on their chart as the source.